# How to setup transparent ssh when there are multiple servers

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy

My desktop is Ubuntu. There is a host class with name `my_host_machine`, which includes several servers like: `my_host_machine_1`, `my_host_machine001`,`my_host_machine__123`, etc. It's uncertain which server will be connected when I ssh `my_host_machine`. And directly connecting to a server like `my_host_machine_1` gets time out.

We are supposed to use one of those servers as a proxy to get access to another server `a_remote_server`. Directly ssh to `a_remote_server` from the local desktop is forbidden.

My question is, can I directly connect to `a_remote_server` from my desktop via proxy command?

I tried setting `~/.ssh/config` on my local desktop as on [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-ssh-proxycommand-passing-through-one-host-gateway-server/) page.

```
Host Remote
  HostName a_remote_server
  User Tom
  Port 22
  ProxyCommand ssh Tom@my_host_machine nc %h %p %r
```

It returns

`nc: port range not valid
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

What's wrong with my config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p Tom@my_host_machine
```

or just

```
ProxyCommand ssh Tom@my_host_machine nc %h %p
```

`netcat` does not accept `username` as a argument.